# pasar mediante metodo post js un formulario mas otras variables

Tags: javascript

tengo un ejercicio en el cual mediante el método post de js, quiero enviar un formulario capturado ya en una variable y además quiero enviar otras variables juntas. dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora pero aun sin funcionar,

```
var datos_usuario = $('#myform').serialize();
$.post('email.php', datos_usuario + { "var_mail": "nuevo" },
                    function(res) {
                        alert(res);
                        if (res == 1) {
                            alertify.success("El Email fue enviado al Usuario");
                            $('#frm-nuevo-usuario')[0].reset(); //limpia el formulario
                            $("#carga_usuario").load("web/mant_usuarios.php");
                        } else {
                            alertify.error("El Email no fue enviado");
                            $('#frm-nuevo-usuario')[0].reset(); //limpia el formulario
                            $("#carga_usuario").load("web/mant_usuarios.php");
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize` te devuelve un query string, si necesitas hacer post debes utilizar otra función donde puedes agregar cualquier elemento extra

```
let datos_usuario = $('#myform').serializeArray();
datos_usuario.push({name: 'var_mail', value: 'nuevo'});

$.post('email.php', datos_usuario);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jonathan por tu ayuda, funciona muy bien